# How to prevent to other checkboxes checked when one checkbox is checked in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have project that using two checkboxes .When one checkbox is checked other one can not be checked. Shortly,I don not want to use two checkbox at the same time.

Here is the  .aspx code:

```
<td ><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChckLctn" Text="Lokasyon" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ChckLctn_CheckedChanged" OnClientClick="showPopup()" /></td>
```

Here is the .cs code:

```
protected void ChckLctn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChckLctn.Checked == true && ChckBrm.Checked == false)
        {
            LokasyonDoldur();
        }
    }

    protected void ChckBrm_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChckLctn.Checked == false && ChckBrm.Checked == true)
        {
            BirimleriDoldur();
        }
    }
```

How can I do this.

Comment: Use radio button instead of checkbox

Comment: Can you show some code you are having trouble with?

Comment: @Ratatouille - with checkboxes you can uncheck both, with radiobuttons you can't uncheck once you checked one.

Comment: @HansKesting so you add a radio for "none" ;p

Comment: Check out this example of radio buttons in a group: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_radiobuttonlist

Comment: You can add a button as "Clear Selection" and use simple js to clear radio button

Comment: @MarcGravell - eh, yes, that would be the easiest way :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`RadioButtons`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `CheckBoxes`, that's what they are designed for. You can use  the [`GroupName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify which radio-buttons belong together.

```
<asp:RadioButton id="Radio1" GroupName="RegularMenu"
         Text="Beef" BackColor="Pink" runat="server"/>

    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton id="Radio2" GroupName="RegularMenu"
         Text="Pork" BackColor="Pink" runat="server"/>

    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton id="Radio3" GroupName="RegularMenu"
         Text="Fish" BackColor="Pink" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this using Javascript as,

here is your checkbox,

```
Male<input type="checkbox" name="Gender" value="Male"/>
Female<input type="checkbox" name="Gender" value="Female"/>
```

And here is your Javascript code::

```
 $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      $("input:checkbox").not($(this)).removeAttr("checked");
      $(this).attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));    
    });
```

for your better reference have a look to this [JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/13bph7t1/)

Comment: I tried your method but I am using asp.net code and js code does not work and I checked JS fiddle link .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use checkboxlist. Use this below javascript

```
var objChkd;
function HandleOnCheck()

{
var chkLst = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1');


if(objChkd && objChkd.checked)

objChkd.checked=false;
objChkd = event.srcElement;

}
```

then resister it to control

```
 CheckBoxList1.Attributes.Add("onclick","return HandleOnCheck()");
```